# onload in for loop returning only the last item (JS)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, onload, color-thief

my code goes like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
                var colorThief = new ColorThief();
                var imgObj = new Image();

                var count = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < assetsArray1.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        // get currency symbol

                        /*var curr_sign = "$";

                        curr_sign = formatter.format(totalvalue1).replace(/[0-9]/g, '').replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace(" ", "");*/

                        allocation_chart.data.labels[i / 2] = assetsArray1[i];

                        imgObj.src = 'icon/' + assetsArray1[i].toLowerCase() + '.png';

                        imgObj.onload = function () {
                            count += colorThief.getColor(imgObj)[0];
                            console.log(count);
                        };
                    } else {
                        allocation_chart.data.datasets[0].data[i / 2 - 0.5] = price1_[i / 2 - 0.5].toFixed(2);
                    }
                }

                allocation_chart.update();
            },
                100);
```

The important part is the onload function. As you can see, imgObj gets changed during the for loop and it's supposed to print out different values after I add `colorThief.getColor(imgObj)[0]` to count. However, the only console message is '176' which would be the value of the last item. The two before are ignored. How can I solve this?

Comment: Try to move the count variable out of the setTimeout block, so it will be global.

Comment: Unfortunately, still not working.

Comment: The problem is, inside the loop you changed imgObj.onload multiple times. And after you changed the onload function for one last time, the image is loaded, and the last function you assigned to be onload callback gets called.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so what can I do to solve this?

Comment: can you try putting this line inside the loop:
`var imgObj = new Image();`
under
`if (i % 2 == 0) {`

Comment: still the same :/